# Как парсить сообщество Facebook через Graph API + Python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Мне нужно спарсить посты из сообщества Facebook. Пытаюсь сделать это через Graph API на Python с библиотекой facebook-sdk. Обнаружил, что могу обратиться через get-запрос только к сообществу, которое создал я. К рандомному паблику я обратиться не могу, выдает

```
{'error': {'message': "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1234567890_SOME_ID' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.....
```

Реально ли сделать то, что я хочу? Буду благодарен любым советам!